# Using && in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've got the following. When I use only `$('#plateread').show()` the **IF.....ELSE** clauses work fine but when I add the `$('#fix_2').show();` with `&&` it doesn't work. Can I not use `&&` symbol in this instance? Have I got it wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select_rg').change(function (){
        if($('#select_rg').val()=='Registered')
            $('#plateread').show() && $('#fix_2').show();
        else
            $('#plateread').hide() && $('#fix_2').hide();
    })
    .change();
});
```

Comment: jQuery methods return the jQuery collection, which is a truthy value.

Comment: *"Can I not use && symbol in this instance?"* Depends on what you want to achieve. You can definitely use it, it's not a syntax error, but it might not achieve the effect you are after. But we can only truly help you if you tell us what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @FelixKling I want both to be hidden if the argument is true. If I need to validate if both the arguments are valid and true, can I use && symbol as in the above code?

Comment: Which arguments are you talking about? Currently you are *showing* two elements if the `if` condition is `true`.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Anyway try `$('#plateread, #fix_2').show();`.

Comment: Well it should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/xx55c5g5/

Comment: Indeed - here's another example of it working without issue: http://jsbin.com/jomacabexuse/1/edit

Comment: @torazaburo Yes your suggestion works! pretty neat compared to what I accepted as the correct answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` is a logical operator and doesnt simultaneous execute two statements, but rather evaluates those statements as either a `true` or `false` value.

Ie. if two conditions are met:

```
If (condition1 && condition1) { ..Do something .. }
```

Do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#select_rg').change(function () {
     if ($('#select_rg').val() == 'Registered') {
         $('#plateread').show();
         $('#fix_2').show();
     } else {
         $('#plateread').hide();
         $('#fix_2').hide();
     }
 })
     .change();
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but actually it should work since the returned jQuery set is a truthy(evaluated to true) value, so both methods are executed.
http://jsfiddle.net/xx55c5g5/

Comment: `function sayHiNicely() { console.log("Hi"); return true; }` `sayHiNicely() && sayHiNicely()` results in "Hi" being written to the console twice.  The JavaScript boolean operator doesn't *simultaneously* evaluate the two expressions, but it does evaluate both expressions *sequentially* if the result of the first expression can be coerced to true.  See http://jsbin.com/jomacabexuse/1/edit for an example of the OP's original code working without issue.  (I didn't down-vote, for what it's worth).

Comment: @SeanVieira interesting. I didnt know that. My answer helped the OP somehow, but if its cool with you I'd like to update my answer with your comment for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Tighten this up a bit with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var select_rg     = $('#select_rg'),
        is_registered = select_rg.val() === 'Registered',
        toggle_elts   = $('#plateread, #fix_2');

    select_rg.change(function() { toggle_elts.toggle(is_registered); });
});
```

Comment: Or bit simpler: `$('#plateread, #fix_2').toggle($('select_rg').val()==='Registered');`

Comment: Yeah, that's better, my jQuery is a bit rusty. Have taken the liberty of incorporating this suggestion into my answer.